# how to reduce the second dimension in pytorch python tensor operation

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have the below tensor with the following shape

```
    seq = dataset['features'][...]
    print(f'shape of seq before unsequeeze {seq.shape}')
    shape of seq before unsequeeze (461, 1024)
```

I am trying to convert the shape in (461, 512) How should I achieve this in  pytorch tensor operation.

examples feature x as below,

```
import torch 
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
x = torch.tensor([[0.1,0.8,0.8,0.4,0.9,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.0,0.5,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.5,1.0,0.1,0.8,0.9,0.0,0.2,0.9,0.8,0.0,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.2,0.9,0.6,0.1,0.2,0.6,0.0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.7,0.4,0.2,0.1,1.0,0.3,0.8,0.1,0.7,0.7,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.2,0.1,1.0,0.6,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.6,0.8,0.0,0.6,0.2,0.1,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.5,0.8,0.4,0.7,0.6,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.8,1.0,0.9,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.4,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.2,0.2,0.7,0.2,0.9,0.6,0.2,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.2,1.0,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.9,0.6,0.0,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.6,0.0,0.7,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.4,1.0,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.1,0.6,0.3,1.0,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.5,1.0,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.1,1.0,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.2,0.0,0.9,0.9,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.7,0.8,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.1,0.5,1.0,0.3,0.2,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.4,0.9,0.2,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.8,1.0,0.1,0.9,0.6,0.5,0.0,0.2,0.8,0.2,0.8,0.5,0.9,0.9,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.8,1.0,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.1,0.0,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.8,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.0,0.3,0.2,0.0,1.0,0.2,0.6,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.6,0.5,1.0,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.7,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.0,0.8,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.7,1.0,0.6,0.6,1.0,0.8,1.0,0.4,0.3,0.2,1.0,0.9,0.2,0.7,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.7,0.6,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.0,1.0,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.3,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.0,0.2,0.9,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.2,0.4,1.0,0.1,0.3,0.8,0.8,0.2,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.1,0.0,0.5,1.0,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.5,0.0,0.2,0.6,0.7,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.0,0.3,0.3,0.8,0.5,0.7,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.3,1.0,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.6,0.2,0.9,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.0,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.1,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.6,1.0,0.7,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.6,0.0,0.6,0.6,0.3,0.7,0.2,1.0,0.6,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.8,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.4,1.0,0.6,1.0,0.3,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,1.0,0.2,0.3,0.9,0.5,0.5,0.4,0.1,0.4,0.0,0.7,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.2,0.8,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.3,0.9,0.1,0.1,0.7,1.0,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.7,0.1,0.2,0.8,1.0,0.5,0.0,0.8,0.2,0.2,0.0,1.0,0.2,1.0,0.5,1.0,0.9,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2,0.9,0.6,0.0,0.3,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.4,0.9,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.0,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.7,0.3,0.3,1.0,0.3,0.6,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.7,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.7,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.0,0.1,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.0,0.4,1.0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.5,0.1,0.4,1.0,0.2,0.8,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.6,0.7,0.5,1.0,0.2,0.8,0.0,0.1,0.2,0.6,0.0,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.2,1.0,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.7,0.0,0.7,0.0,0.7,0.9,0.1,0.2,0.8,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.0,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.9,0.4,1.0,0.8,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.2,0.7,0.4,0.0,1.0,0.7,0.3,0.6,0.9,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.9,0.7,0.2,1.0,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.0,0.3,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.7,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.8,0.0,0.9,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.4,1.0,0.2,0.3,0.0,0.5,1.0,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.9,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.0,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.0,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.6,0.2,0.8,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.9,0.4,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.6,0.1,0.9,1.0,1.0,0.8,0.8,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.6,0.4,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8,1.0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.3,0.7,0.9,0.6,1.0,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.9,0.0,0.3,0.7,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.6,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.4,0.1,0.4,1.0,0.1,0.7,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.4,1.0,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.7,0.0,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.9,0.8,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.0,0.3,0.2,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.2,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.1,0.0,0.3,0.6,0.4,1.0,1.0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.0,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.1,1.0,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.9,0.8],
[0.5,0.6,0.0,0.9,0.9,0.4,0.4,0.9,0.1,0.7,0.8,0.7,1.0,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.9,1.0,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.6,0.1,1.0,0.8,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.0,0.5,0.3,0.9,0.5,0.0,0.9,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.0,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.8,0.7,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.8,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.0,0.7,0.0,0.1,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.1,0.8,0.9,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.9,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.6,0.7,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.7,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.4,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.7,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.1,0.9,0.9,0.6,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.4,0.8,0.9,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.9,1.0,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.3,0.1,1.0,0.2,0.9,0.2,0.9,0.7,0.9,1.0,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.7,0.0,0.3,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.5,0.0,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.0,0.8,0.5,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.9,0.0,0.8,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.9,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.5,0.8,1.0,0.4,1.0,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.8,1.0,0.6,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.6,1.0,0.4,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.1,1.0,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.0,0.6,0.5,1.0,0.6,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.7,1.0,0.9,1.0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.1,0.9,0.6,0.9,0.9,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.0,0.0,0.2,0.2,0.9,0.9,0.6,1.0,0.2,0.7,1.0,0.8,1.0,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.9,0.5,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.1,0.5,0.2,1.0,0.7,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.0,1.0,0.8,1.0,0.1,0.2,0.9,0.4,0.8,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.1,0.3,0.0,0.7,0.6,0.9,0.4,0.4,0.9,0.4,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.9,1.0,0.8,0.2,0.2,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.4,0.6,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.0,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.0,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.9,1.0,0.7,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.4,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.9,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.0,0.4,0.0,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.7,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.8,0.6,0.9,0.1,0.4,0.0,0.4,0.0,0.4,0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.8,0.9,0.2,0.0,0.6,0.3,1.0,0.6,0.7,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.9,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.0,0.8,0.5,0.0,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.8,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.0,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.9,1.0,0.8,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.0,0.1,1.0,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.6,0.1,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.5,1.0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1,0.7,1.0,0.7,0.6,0.9,1.0,0.4,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.4,0.0,0.0,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.9,0.5,0.1,0.3,0.9,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.5,0.4,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.6,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,0.7,0.7,0.1,0.3,1.0,0.4,0.4,0.0,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.5,0.1,0.6,0.9,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.0,0.1,1.0,0.6,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.2,0.7,0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.0,0.9,0.3,0.2,0.9,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.5,0.9,0.5,0.4,0.3,1.0,0.7,0.5,0.1,0.0,0.3,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.1,0.8,0.0,0.9,0.0,0.0,0.7,0.6,1.0,0.5,0.9,0.7,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.9,0.4,0.3,0.3,1.0,0.2,1.0,0.3,0.7,0.9,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.0,0.2,0.8,0.3,1.0,0.5,0.0,0.7,0.9,0.3,0.3,0.9,0.9,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.6,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.0,0.6,0.0,0.1,0.9,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5,1.0,0.3,0.2,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.9,0.1,0.8,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.5,1.0,0.1,0.7,0.4,0.7,0.7,0.9,0.9,1.0,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.2,0.0,0.5,0.2,1.0,0.7,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.6,0.0,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.1,0.7,1.0,0.1,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.1,0.0,0.1,0.6,0.1,1.0,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.1,0.3,0.8,0.7,0.0,0.4,0.5,0.2,0.0,0.5,0.8,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.9,0.9,0.3,0.5,0.3,1.0,0.8,0.7,0.9,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.8,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.3,0.1,0.9,0.2,0.4,0.9,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.2,1.0,0.9,0.8,0.2,0.2,1.0,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.0,0.5,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.6,0.0,0.1,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.7,0.2,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.2,1.0,1.0,0.7,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.3,0.6,0.5,1.0,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.0,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.3,0.9,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.1,0.0,0.7,0.5,1.0,0.3,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.2,0.9,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.2,0.7,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.3,0.2]]).to(
    device, dtype=torch.int64
)

x.shape
torch.Size([2, 1024])
```

I need to reduce  the feature size to 512 keeping the first dim batch size in tact,

```
x.shape
torch.Size([2, 512])
```

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you want to reduce it. Average? Max? Min? Another Op? In a concrete case, if you had `[[1,2,3,4]]`, what would be the 2 elements in the resulting tensor?

Comment: I wanted to reduce the  dimensions alone..I have found some results as shared below thank you for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z = torch.narrow(x,1,0,512)
z.shape
torch.Size([2, 512])
```

if you use x.unsqueeze(0), then the dim 2 will require the change,

```
z = torch.narrow(x,2,0,512)
```

Comment: Do you realize that this is only selecting the first 512 elements? It is exactly the same as `z = x[:, 0:512]` when `dim=1`.

Comment: @Berriel I tried one such syntax let me try your  suggestion and see. you are right, but i had unsequeezed  X, then how does the syntax works.

Comment: The point is: is that what you wanted? Reduce by selecting?

Comment: need to reduce but I had another Dimension also added to it.

Comment: Then it would be `x[:, :, :512]`, but that is not the point. Nevermind.